# Google Cloud DNS - All zones on the same shard

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I'm looking to use Cloud DNS to manage a large set of customer custom domain zones. I've setup all the logic to create the zones with the required records. I'd also like to have our customers just see a small set of vanity nameservers e.g. `ns1.my-domain.com`, `ns2.my-domain.com`, `ns3.my-domain.com`.

The problem I'm having is each zone could be created on any one of the nameserver shards, of cause this means that we can't just point those name servers mentioned above to a specific shard.

The solution we've found is pointing each vanity name server to all shards where each ns1.my-domain.com A record contains a list of IP's instead of one:

```
216.239.32.106 // A Shard
216.239.32.107 // B Shard
216.239.32.108 // C Shard
216.239.32.109 // D Shard
216.239.32.110 // E Shard
```

This posses one rather large issue which is anyone could just create a zone with the same domain name and there is a chance it will use that one instead. Unless when we create the zone we try to create as many as we can, until all shards contain the zone.

It'd be great if there is either away to specify which shard to use when creating the zone or selecting one zone for the whole project. But I've had no luck finding a way to do either of these. It may be the case that Cloud DNS just isn't the right service for us, but I would like to avoid having a separate service for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Do not use words like `large`. Specify exact numbers or ranges of numbers. Tip: do not worry about sharding unless you are the size of IBM. Google's DNS server deliver billions of queries. Your sites will not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Using custom vanity nameservers with Cloud DNS is currently not supported, however there is an existing [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/120844212) opened for this.

Regarding the 5 shards mentioned, at most there can be 5 Cloud DNS zones using exactly the same domain name, since each shard can only be used [once by a single domain](https://cloud.google.com/dns/quotas#name_server_limits) this way you could effectively use all the shards to prevent them from being used on other projects for the same domain name.